# How to get a specific cell in a user selected range in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, range, excel-interop, excel-addins

I create my frist Excel Add-In and want to finde specific cells in a range the user select.

I know the Columns in which the values are that I need. So I test it with:

```
Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;
Excel.Range firstValue = selection.Columns["I"].Find("*", Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
```

now I have the first value from column "I"

this works fine when the "selection" the user makes begins in column "A"

If the user select for excample from C2 to H20 the code cant find column "I"
I become than an other range, not the "I" column.

I think for him is "I" always "9". 
When the user select from "C2" to "H20" in the new range is colum "C" = "0" and column "L" = 9  so the code select column "L" even if I write "I" in the code.

Have anyone an idea how can I read the specific column or cell I want inner the selection of the user no matter where the user Begins with his selection?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, when you are dealing with a selection of cells the cell in hte top-left becomes the equivalent of A1 when dealing with cell references within that selection and other cells are referenced by the rows and columns they are offset to the top-left cell.

If you are looking to search within an area of column I truncated by the user selection of rows then I would suggest the [_Application.Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.intersect.aspx).

If you are looking to search in a section of column I with the selections top and bottom row as boundaries of column I even if there is not intersection, define the first cell in column I using the selection.cells[1].row and resize it by selection.rows.count.